# Setting external font for selected item of the spinner android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, textview, android-spinner, android-fonts

I have set a text view to a array adapter in order to show the selected item of the spinner. This is the code for the array adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDitrict =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.district_array,
                    R.layout.spinner_item);
adapterDitrict.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerDitrict.setAdapter(adapterDitrict);`
```

`

Here R.layout.spinner_item is the text box used to display the selected item of the spinner. Note that this text view is not in the layout of the activity. Now I want to apply a external font to this text box. But I can't get a reference to this text view using findviewbyid since it is not in the activities layout. I am using setTypeface to set the external font. So how to show the selected item of the spinner is the text view using a external font. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by 2 ways, first one is either take custom adapter and manage your view, and second one override your getView method for this current adapater only.

**For First option of custom adapter folow below link**

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

**For second option check my answer below**

```
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDitrict = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.district_array,
                    R.layout.spinner_item)
  {
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeFace(Your Tyope Face);
            return v;
       }
  };
```

Check both answer and use any one as per your requirement.